# How does XMPP handle duplicate messages?

Tags: xmpp, chat

There could be scenarios where client get disconnected from server just after receiving a message. Server is not sure if the client received the message or not and re-sends the message. Now, how does client identifies whether this message is new or already processed by it? Does XMPP associates any unique identifier with every message to eliminate duplicates?

Answer (score 1):

Servers do not re-deliver messages by default, just because the server is "not sure" if the client received it. Sent to client == "delivered".

However for greater reliability, it is possible to use the [XEP-0198](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0198.html) extension. This avoids duplicate messages because when the client reconnects to the server, it tells the server how many messages (stanzas, rather) it received. The server compares this to the number of stanzas it sent to the client. If the client did not receive them all, it re-sends only the ones that the client missed.

This mechanism avoids having to assign a unique identifier to every message.

Comment: What I understood from the link you shared is that a unique id is associated with every stanza and it's used for removing duplicate stanza. Am I correct?


Doc : 
"Because unacknowledged stanzas might have been received by the other party, resending them might result in duplicates; there is no way to prevent such a result in this protocol, although use of the XMPP 'id' attribute on all stanzas can at least assist the intended recipients in weeding out duplicate stanzas."